# Comparing two sets to find out whether first set is a subset of other

Tags: java, android

I am making a android app to choose a product based on specs and send sms with product code.
I have a huge list of products with diff specifications.
I need to compare approx. 23 specs to choose a product.
I know I can use  multiple if statements or nested ifs but I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same. I can choose product only if all 23 specs are exactly same.
All specs are stored in variable like M1 to M49 and mapped against product codes.

SMS part is already done but I am confused to compare so many variables.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Give me the project and I'll do it. :D

Comment: M1 to M49 are Strings?

Comment: Yes all M1 to M49 are strings, but I need to compare only 23 specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) function of JAVA

```
class Check
{
static String s[] = { "q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a",
               "mmmmm","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v" };

static String s1[] = {"b","n","m","er","re","ew","j","k","x","qq","ww","ee","c","v","t","y","d","f","g","h",
               "u","rr","yyy","uuu","ttt","trew","rerer","q","w","vv","gg","hh","tt","tr","ww","e","i"
               ,"eww","qwe","wer","o","p","a","s","ds","cv","r","l","z"};

public static void main(String arags[])
{
   Set<String> originalset = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(s1));
   Set<String> testset = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(s));        
   originalset.retainAll(testset);
    if(originalset.size()==23)
    {
        System.out.println("Sucess 23 matches found");
    }
    else
    {
          System.out.println("Fail 23 matches not found");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

```
1. Put both of them into a HashSet. A HashSet searches faster and doesn't allow duplicate elements.
2. Find if first hashset is a subset of second hashset.


import java.util.Iterator;


public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s[] = { "q","q","q","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a",
                   "m","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v" };

        String s1[] = {"b","n","m","q","q","er","re","ew","j","k","x","qq","ww","ee","c","v","t","y","d","f","g","h",
                   "u","rr","yyy","uuu","ttt","trew","rerer","q","w","vv","gg","hh","tt","tr","ww","e","i"
                   ,"eww","qwe","wer","o","p","a","s","ds","cv","r","l","z"};

       /* System.out.println("Length of s : " + s.length);
        System.out.println("Length of s1 : " + s1.length);
        Arrays.sort(s);
        Arrays.sort(s1);

        display(s);
        display(s1);
        int j=0;
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++) {
            if(s[j].equals(s1[i])) {

                count++;
                j++;
                if(j==23) break;
            }
        }
        if(j==23) System.out.println("23 matches found");
        else System.out.println("23 matches not found");
        */

        HashSet<String> hs1 = createSet(s);
        HashSet<String> hs2 = createSet(s1);
        System.out.println(h1SubsetOfh2(hs1, hs2));
    }

    public static HashSet<String> createSet(String[] sArr) {
        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<sArr.length;i++) {
            hs.add(sArr[i]);
        }
        return hs;
    }

    public static boolean h1SubsetOfh2(HashSet<String> hs1,HashSet<String> hs2) {
        Iterator<String> it = hs1.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            if(!hs2.contains(it.next()))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think I have not explained properly. I have 23 strings and I need to compare it with M1 to M49 and find out if my 23 strings are equals M1 to M49. I can choose product only if all 23 strings matches with any of 49 specs. Your code compares same string to 49 specs.

Comment: you mean to say there are 23 strings in m1 to m49 that matches exactly with the 23 strings you are passing.

Comment: No. I have 23 strings, this is my set. M1 to M49 are 49 strings, this is the set available on server. I need to check if my 23 strings are there in 49 strings or not. Say, my 1st string matches with M10, 2nd matches with M5, 3rd is matching with M40 and so on for all 23 string. Finally if there is a match for each and every 23 strings in M1 to M49, I can choose the product. Hope I am clear this time.

Comment: Are all 23 strings at your side unique?. Also the 49 strings at server side are unique?

Comment: All 23 strings may or may not be unique as it is derived at runtime by the options chosen by the user. 49 server side strings also not unique. If one of my string matches two server strings or vice versa, is not a problem.

Comment: in your set of 23 , suppose there is a string "a" two times and on server side strings of 49, "a" is found only once , 2 out of 23 strings are matched or count would be one.

Comment: Count will be 2 out of 23 strings.

Comment: Ok , then using hashsets is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s[] = { "q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a",
                   "mmmmm","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v" };

    String s1[] = {"b","n","m","er","re","ew","j","k","x","qq","ww","ee","c","v","t","y","d","f","g","h",
                   "u","rr","yyy","uuu","ttt","trew","rerer","q","w","vv","gg","hh","tt","tr","ww","e","i"
                   ,"eww","qwe","wer","o","p","a","s","ds","cv","r","l","z"};

        System.out.println("Length of s : " + s.length);
        System.out.println("Length of s1 : " + s1.length);
        Arrays.sort(s);
        Arrays.sort(s1);

        display(s);
        display(s1);
        int j=0;
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++) {
            if(s[j].equals(s1[i])) {

                count++;
                j++;
                if(j==23) break;
            }
        }
        if(j==23) System.out.println("23 matches found");
        else System.out.println("23 matches not found");


    }
    public static void display(String a[]) {

        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }



}
```

Try this one.

Comment: @Madiya : Try the other solution I posted that is using hashsets. That will work for all conditions and is efficient. ANd upvote the answer if you feel that this version of answer is correct